# Make a manual credit memo or refund without an order

Tags: admin, orders, creditmemo, refund

Is there any way to manually create a credit order in the Magento backend, without an actual order being attached?

This is the situation: I am making a refund on an order which was done before I started to use Magento. So no corresponding order in my system.

The accountant needs an credit memo when I refund this. I could create one in the old system or just type one but this would create an inconsistent numbering and layout in my credit memo's (which actually is a small problem, but i was wondering)

Comment: As far as I know I don't think this is easy to do, just typing one will probably save you a lot of headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to create a credit memo for an order that does not exist. It is a problem I have had to face in the past when I have migrated a solution from one platform to another. In some cases I have imported an amount of previous orders into magento so that the merchant can deal with such situations but for a single event as you describe it would take more time than creating one my had.

The reason for not being able to create a credit memo without an order is down to the way that data is stored within Magento. Orders have a relationship / history to payment, customer address etc. A credit memo would require at minimum a order entity ID that will not exist within your system so there would be no integrity for the data. No way to view load edit save etc.

Comment: Thanks for explaining and it was actually what i thought the reaction would be. Makes sense, it would be great to have the possibilyi in Magento to manually overwrite some things though.

Answer (score 0):

As also mentioned by the commetors Magento does not have this function. I actually came up with something that is working for me. I think it's worth sharing.

I created an new store with the exact same setting as my webshop. Only order and invoice mails are not send (system > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails). Also the transactional mails are for the credit is slightly edited (i removed all the references to orders).

In the new store i create the order I want to invoice. After that I simpy create an invoice for this order. The result is what i wanted: A single credit Memo from Magento.